# How do we handle suggested edits that remove links to retailers?

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across this [suggested edit](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4116).

The edit description states:

> advertisement redacted

Then only change was to remove mentions of a link to `tokopedia.com`. Note that this was not an actual link to the site.

The original text was:

> Basically the top 6 core have the same socket type and almost the same benchmark result. However, Intel Core i7 3770 is simply cheaper. It's only $335. I actually got a used one for $200 from tokopedia.com
>
> Xeon 1290 is simply too expensive and not available on tokopedia.com

---

At first, I wanted to reject this edit. The answer clearly explains where the user found the product for a certain price. It doesn't link directly to the product though.

However, the edit comment made me pause and wonder "Is this spam?" In my opinion it does not appear to be.

I am conflicted now. Should these off hand comments about retailers be removed? (I am thinking "No")

---

My question:

- Should we be removing links to retailers like this? I am reading it as a valid attempt to answer the question *and* provide context to where certain prices and products are available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree. I don't see any reason to remove links unless there's *actually evidence* that they are spam. I can't find any in this case.

And if there *is* evidence, this should be handled with a moderator flag. Not a suggested edit.

Comment: Agreed. This is just like any other link to a seller, and the fact that the seller in question isn't well-known doesn't change anything. Only evidence of spam is a reason to remove the link.